# Javascript variable not setting correctly for first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

My problem is that my variable `flag` is not getting updated some how, I have even tried to do that with `setTimeout` function but no luck!

**JavaScript**

```
function confirmed(msg, okFtn, cnclFtn){
    flag=false;
    $(document.createElement('div')).html('\
        <div style="max-width:250px;width:100%;">'+msg+'\
        <p>\
            <button value="yes" class="button small gradient blue left rnd5 cnfrm">OK</button>\
            <button value="no" class="button small gradient blue left rnd5 cnfrm">Cancel</button>\
        </p></div>')
        .modal({
            onShow: function (dialog) {
                $('.simplemodal-close').remove();
                $("#simplemodal-container").css({'height': 'auto','width':'auto'});
                $(window).trigger('resize.simplemodal'); 
            },
            onClose: function(){
                console.log(flag);
                if(flag)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        });
    $('button.cnfrm').click(function(){
        flag=true;
        if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
            if(okFtn && typeof okFtn === 'function')
                okFtn();
        } else {
            if(cnclFtn && typeof cnclFtn === 'function')
                cnclFtn();
        }
        setTimeout(function(){$.modal.close();}, 1000);
    });
}
```

This is [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5LjXL/) of what I am saying.

Since variable is not setting up so `$.modal.close()` is not working fine, what I want is just closing modal dialog if and only if button `OK` or `cancel` is clicked.

Comment: Which variable is not being set? Your explanation is too sparse.

Comment: you can see my edit `flag` is not setting up @EvanKnowles

Comment: Have you tried specifically declaring it as `var flag` instead of using the implicit global?

Comment: yup I tried that too but no luck with that, then I tried to make it global to see if it works. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

From the documentation:

onClose: Useful for adding effects to the closing of the modal dialog elements. After you’ve applied effects, etc., **you’ll need to call $.modal.close()**; so SimpleModal can re-insert the data correctly and clean up the dialog elements.

You need to include a call to `$.modal.close()` in your `onClose()` handler, e.g.

```
        onClose: function(){
            console.log(flag);
            if(flag) $.modal.close();
        }
```

ps. As for the `flag` variable, it's getting set up exactly as you expected it to. It's not the problem.